# save wordcloud in loop using python

Tags: python, loops, word-cloud

I am trying to generate wordcloud for different category in data. I am able to generate wordcloud in loop. Please refer to below script.

```
import pandas as pd
from wordcloud import WordCloud,STOPWORDS
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt       

##Read data file
df = pd.read_csv("Data.csv",encoding='cp1252')

def wordcloud_draw(data, color = 'black'):
    words = ' '.join(data)
    cleaned_word = " ".join([word for word in words.split()
                            if 'http' not in word
                                and not word.startswith('@')
                                and not word.startswith('#')
                                and word != 'RT'
                            ])
    wordcloud = WordCloud(stopwords=STOPWORDS,
                      background_color=color,
                      width=2500,
                      height=2000
                     ).generate(cleaned_word)
    plt.figure(1,figsize=(13, 13))
    plt.imshow(wordcloud)
    plt.axis('off')
    plt.title('Wordcloud of key')
    plt.savefig('(key).png')
    plt.close()

dict_of_Categorization = {k: v for k, v in df.groupby('Categorization')}

for key, value in dict_of_Categorization.items():
    num_Descriptions = len(value)
    if (num_Descriptions >= 50):
        num_Descriptions
        wordcloud_draw(value["Description"],'white')
```

Now I want to save each wordcloud based on their key (contains category). I tried saving in function which used to create wordcloud, but it is not working as it is not using iterative values instead it saves as "(key).png" and overwrite next wordclod on the same. Can anyone help me here.

Comment: It saves as `(key).png` because you said so in the code. You need to pass the key as an argument into the `wordcloud_draw` function and then use it to create the filename.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass `key` to your `wordcloud_draw()` function and then use it to create the necessary strings as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
from wordcloud import WordCloud,STOPWORDS
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt       

#Read data file
df = pd.read_csv("Data.csv", encoding='cp1252')

def wordcloud_draw(data, key, color='black'):
    words = ' '.join(data)
    cleaned_word = " ".join([word for word in words.split()
                            if 'http' not in word
                                and not word.startswith('@')
                                and not word.startswith('#')
                                and word != 'RT'
                            ])
    wordcloud = WordCloud(stopwords=STOPWORDS,
                      background_color=color,
                      width=2500,
                      height=2000
                     ).generate(cleaned_word)
    plt.figure(1,figsize=(13, 13))
    plt.imshow(wordcloud)
    plt.axis('off')
    plt.title('Wordcloud of key "{}"'.format(key))
    plt.savefig('{}.png'.format(key))
    plt.close()

dict_of_Categorization = {k: v for k, v in df.groupby('Categorization')}

for key, value in dict_of_Categorization.items():
    num_Descriptions = len(value)
    if (num_Descriptions >= 50):
        num_Descriptions
        wordcloud_draw(value["Description"], key, 'white')
```

Comment: Your suggestion helped me. Thank you very much again.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to pass the key as an argument to your wordcloud_draw function. For example:

```
import pandas as pd
from wordcloud import WordCloud,STOPWORDS
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt       

##Read data file
df = pd.read_csv("Data.csv",encoding='cp1252')

def wordcloud_draw(data, save_name, color = 'black'):
    words = ' '.join(data)
    cleaned_word = " ".join([word for word in words.split()
                            if 'http' not in word
                                and not word.startswith('@')
                                and not word.startswith('#')
                                and word != 'RT'
                            ])
    wordcloud = WordCloud(stopwords=STOPWORDS,
                      background_color=color,
                      width=2500,
                      height=2000
                     ).generate(cleaned_word)
    plt.figure(1,figsize=(13, 13))
    plt.imshow(wordcloud)
    plt.axis('off')
    plt.title('Wordcloud of key')
    plt.savefig(savename+'.png')
    plt.close()

dict_of_Categorization = {k: v for k, v in df.groupby('Categorization')}

for key, value in dict_of_Categorization.items():
    num_Descriptions = len(value)
    if (num_Descriptions >= 50):
        num_Descriptions
        wordcloud_draw(value["Description"],key,'white')
```

Comment: thank you very much for your help. It helps a lot able to save plots . Thank you very much again